# Remove Text, White Space That Follows Comment Marker in String With JavaScript - Create New Line In String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, newline, markers

I'm trying to solve [this CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51c8e37cee245da6b40000bd/train/javascript) challenge:

> Complete the solution so that it strips all text that follows any of a set of comment markers passed in. Any whitespace at the end of the line should also be stripped out.
>
> Given an input string of:
>
> ```
> apples, pears # and bananas
> grapes
> bananas !apples
> ```
>
> The output expected would be:
>
> ```
> apples, pears
> grapes
> bananas
> ```

So far I've tried:

```
function solution(input, markers) {
  
  let string = input.split();
  let newString = " ";

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    
    let words = string[i];
    //console.log(words);

    if (words.includes(markers || "/n")) {
      //go to the next line and keep building newString
    }
    newString += words;
  }
  return newString.toString();
}
```

And this is returning `apples,pears#andbananas/ngrapes/nbananas!apples` because, as you can see, I don't know how to create a new line in the string when one of the markers is present, or when `/n` is present.

I've tried

```
if (words.includes(markers || "/n")) {
  //go to the next line and keep building newString
  newString += "\n";
}
```

and

```
if (words.includes(markers || "/n")) {
  //go to the next line and keep building newString
  words + "\n";
}
```

but neither of these are having any effect.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. There is no need to split the string by spaces. Also, a newline character is `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: Okay so I've changed `let string = input.split(" ");` to `let string = input.split();`, and changed `/n` to `\n`\ in my if-statements.

Comment: What advantage do you see in creating `string` like that? Do you use the console at all, to inspect intermediate results?

Comment: so that I can iterate through the words in the `string` to check if they are one of the `markers`. If they're a `marker`, stop iteration through that line and start a new line to add to the `newString`.

Comment: But you don't have a line. `input.split()` will split the whole text into individual characters, which hardly gives any advantage over just using the input as-is. That is why I asked: do you use the console?

Comment: Yes I was doing a `console.log` after `words`. If I do a `console.log` after `string`, I'll get `[ 'apples, pears # and bananas /ngrapes /nbananas !apples' ]`.

Comment: So I don't need to split the string into an array in order to loop through it? Can you loop through a string in JavaScript?

Comment: Indeed, you can.

Comment: Please use the console to inspect all aspects of your code. For instance, the argument to `includes` makes no sense. Think about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191339/discussion-between-happyhands31-and-trincot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sites that have coding challenges often have levels (like CodeWars). In this case I would suggest to stick a bit longer with the easier levels until you are really fluent in solving them.

Also check the solutions that others have submitted: a lot can be learned from that.

I say this because there are so many things wrong in your code, that it seems you will benefit more from covering easier levels a bit longer, than from just grabbing a solution here and posting it.

Some comments on your code:

- You initialise your `newString` with a space. That is a wrong start. That space is not warranted to be there. You should only take characters from the input. It should be an empty string.
- The newline character is not `"/n"`, but `"\n"`
- `input.split()` converts a string to an array of characters. If your aim was to make it possible to access characters through indexing, then realise that you can do so with a string as well: `input[i]` gives you the character at that offset.
- Variable names are important. Naming a variable `string` is not very helpful. Nor is `words`, when actually it holds *one* character. So `character` would be a better choice.
- `includes` expects a string as argument, but you pass `markers`. The `|| "/n"` has no additional value, because `markers` is a truthy value and so `||` will stop right there (short-circuit evaluation). And as `markers` is an array, not a string, `includes` converts that value into a comma-separated string. Obviously that string is very unlikely to occur in your input. You need to test for each marker character individually, and also check for the newline character.
- The body of your `if` statement is empty (in your main attempt). This cannot be useful. Maybe you were looking for `continue;` which will skip the rest of the loop and continue with the next iteration of it.
- There is no provision to skip the characters that *follow* a marker character.
- You have no provision to eliminate spacing that occurs before a marker character.
- `newString` is a string, so there is no need to call `newString.toString();`

Trying to stay with your idea, here is your code corrected:

```
function solution(input, markers) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let character = input[i];
    if (markers.includes(character)) {
        // move i to just before the end of the current line
        i = input.indexOf("\n", i)-1;
        // Remove the white space that we already added at the end
        newString = newString.trimRight();
        // If no newline character at end of last line: break
        if (i < 0) break;
        // Skip rest of this iteration
        continue;
    }
    newString += input[i];    
  }
  return newString;
}
```

But there are easier ways to do this. For instance, by splitting your input into lines first.

Here is the solution I posted:

```
const solution = (input, markers) =>
    input.split("\n").map(line => 
        markers.reduce((line, marker) => 
            line.split(marker, 1)[0].trimRight(), line)).join("\n");
```